# Notebook wakes up after disconnecting mouse

Tags: windows-7, sleep

My Win7 notebook wakes up from sleep after disconnecting mouse. It is very annoying since I usually disconnect the mouse when I want to put it in the bag and leave. Vista behaves in the same manner. How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Control Panel->  (window/startmenu -> control panel)
Mouse-> (icon)
Hardware-> (tab) 
Properties-> (button)
Change Setting-> (button:vista/win 7 only)
PowerManagement-> (tab)
Allow this device to bring the computer out of standby (checkbox)

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem entirely, because the mouse can't wake the computer at all (not just on unplugging)... but since it's a laptop mouse, I suspect it's a minor inconvenience.