# Laptop wakes up from Sleep mode when I remove the mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notebook wakes up after disconnecting mouse](https://superuser.com/questions/64684/notebook-wakes-up-after-disconnecting-mouse)

On my new laptop the following happens:

1. I press the Power button and the computer goes to sleep. OK.
2. I unplug the cables, and when I pull the USB mouse the computer wakes up again.

Any idea how I can prevent that?

It is a Toshiba Qosmio G50, running Windows 7 Ultimate.

In order to establisg the cause, I would like to hear if anybody ran into the same problem with either Win7 on a laptop or a Qosmio running Vista or XP?

Comment: I have a Windows 7 Professional laptop that does the same thing (ASUS brand, though).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go in to Device Management (Click Start/Orb, Right Click on `Computer` and click `Manage`. Click Device Manager).

Next Expand "Mice and other pointing devices".

Click the Power Management tab and untick "Allow this device to wake the computer"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit that I haven't used Windows 7, but in XP you can go into the device manager to control power management properties of a device.   In XP, the USB mouse would have a checkbox under the Power Management tab to permit allowing the device to wake the system from standby - unchecking the box it turns this option off.

Perhaps a similar option is in Windows 7.